# Difficulty webscraping site for data with Powershell

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

Im attempting to get data off this site.  Im trying get the data from classname 'headline-title-nolink' . but not having luck?
What am I doing wrong?

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.financialjuice.com/home

$title = $WebResponse.ParsedHtml.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName('span') | Where { $_.ClassName -match 'headline-title-nolink'}

$title
```

[image]

[image]
Im attempting to retrieve the Headline and the datetime (I realize I dont have a datetime query in my code above)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate on what you expect and what you actually see. Also, have you tried save the results of your `Invoke-WebRequest` to a file and inspecting it?

Comment: I tried it and your code seems to work. Are you sure there is ```{ $_.ClassName -match 'headline-title-nolink'}```

Comment: Ive elaborated on my question to the board.  Thank you

Comment: I think it is using a capatcha on the site. so unable.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is a difference between the DOM tree on the finally rendered page (the thing you are looking at with dev tools) and the HTML source you get when you request specific URL. Check the page source, not the DOM tree. Check the network tab in browser dev tools, too, to see how many requests are involved in rendering the page.

Answer (score 0):

The titles are pulled in dynamically when JavaScript runs in the browser. In the browser additional web traffic is generated. Included in that traffic is a request to `https://www.financialjuice.com/FJService.asmx/GetPreviousNews` that includes a query string determining what should be returned.

That query string has an `info` parameter you can pick up, via regex, from the page you were originally visiting. Concatenate that retrieved value into the query string that has fixed values you can use as shown below. Make the new request, parse out the content that needs to be re-parsed as JSON. Finally, extract the titles.

```
$url = "https://www.financialjuice.com/home"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
$s = $response.ToString()
$is_present = $s -match "var info = '(.*?)'" 

if($is_present){
  $id = $Matches[1]
  $new_url = 'https://www.financialjuice.com/FJService.asmx/GetPreviousNews?info="' + [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($id) + `
              '"&TimeOffset=0&tabID=0&oldID=0&TickerID=0&FeedCompanyID=0&strSearch=""&extraNID=0'

  $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $new_url -Method GET -ContentType application/json # -Headers $headers

  $json = $response.d | ConvertFrom-Json

  Foreach($i in $json){Write-Host $i.title}
}
```